# If the vinyl floor glue was not tacky when flooring was put down, will it stick?

Tags: flooring, adhesive, vinyl

I had someone put down a sheet of vinyl flooring on existing vinyl flooring. It was cleaned very well, dried and then the new vinyl was applied; however, the person doing the job did not allow time for the glue to get tacky. He just put down the new floor immediately after applying the glue. My question is, will it stick? If not, can I pull up the flooring and do it again?

Comment: It will, just the sticking process will take much longer

Comment: in the cool season the extra time isn't as critical to getting an even adhesion (no bubbles, slipping, etc) since the air has so much less moisture than say, august in US.

Answer (score 1):

It will stick eventually when the glue had time to start drying.

The process might take much longer now, since limited exposure to air.

No need to remove and reapply.

That would just create a mess.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers. I feel a lot better now.